# Hooks for the background compilation in Visual Studio 2008/2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

Is there a set of events, a service, or any other API in the Visual Studio SDK for Visual Studio 2008 and/or Visual Studio 2010 that allows you to hook into the background compilation service and listen for background compilation events?

Comment: EnvDTE.BuildEvents.  What do you *really* want to do?

Comment: @Hans, BuildEvents is for explicit builds, @Håvard is asking about the background processing which is very different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there are no publicly exposed events for listening to the background compiler in Visual Studio.  If such an interface did exist it would be language specific.  There is no general background compiler in Visual Studio.  Every language handles background processing differently.

VB.Net is the only language which truly has a background compiler.  The other language services do not actually do the full compilation in the background but more of an on demand interpretation.

Comment: So to be clear, there is no way to hook into the background compiler for C#, be it through events or any other means?